# How do I navigate to my Visual Studio's App_Data folder in relative way

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage, relative-path

I have an ASP.NET Web Api project which has **App_Data** folder. Inside of it I have a database file(.sqlite) which I use in my application. There's a connection string to it that resides in my configuration files. The path is absolute and includes my current file structure(**C:\Something\Other\App_Data\MyDb.sqlite**). The problem is that I want to host it on Azure and most likely Azure won't find this path. So, for that purpose I would like to use a relative path so on Azure the file gets properly located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your server side code (C#, VB.NET, etc.) you can use: `~/App_Data/`.

If you are trying to reach the directory within a connection string you can use: `Data Source=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.sdf`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Azure web app with single instance, please try the connection string that Jesse Johnson provided. If your web app need scale across multiple machines, I think SqlLite is not suitable for you to use. Azure Web App ARR will dispatch the request to some instance, and your data will saved to this instance via SqlLite. If next time the request is dispatched to another instance, I think you could not read the data you saved before. I think it is better to choose Azure Storage or Azure SQL to save your data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'single instance'? I have a ASP.NET Web Api that is hosted there and runs like a separate application.

Comment: We can scale out our Web api in Azure portal. I think [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/) could help you with the concept. More instance could help your web api to handle very large requests. And as I said in my reply, if you use SqlLite, sometimes you could not get the data correctly.  This is the limitation of SqlLite in Azure web app